# Jquery not passing any parameters data

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

My Code is as below for Javascript

```
  $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "page/rSales.aspx",
         data: { ListID: '1', ItemName: 'test' },       
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (res) {
             alert('Success');
         },
         error: function (res) {
            alert('Fail');
         }
     });
```

I use http tracer tools to trace whether or not the parameter is passing on to my backend - and it is not. I have also tried adding  `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`, adjust parameter by adding colon, but none of it is working.

My Backend code C# :

```
Request.Params["ListID"].ToString();
```

It always returns null, due to the parameter not passing on. I am wondering what is causing this problem and how should I resolve it.

Comment: The above code seems to be working when I try it in w3schools, and then check the outcome in the developer tools network panel.

Comment: @MiquelColl how to apply ?

Comment: I found out that my code only work in chrome ...Firefox will not work

Answer (score 0):

The Request.Params collection does not support JSON requests, so you have to parse response body manually (or send it as form data).
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.params(v=vs.110).aspx says "Gets a combined collection of QueryString, Form, Cookies, and ServerVariables items."

Answer (score 0):

For firefox you declare **var event;** before your ajax call this is very well known issue in firefox.